# Why is connecting to postgresql server so slow?

Tags: postgresql, odbc, remote-access, remote-server

I have a remote server on a cloud with postgresql 9.4 running and a client app using an odbc connection.

My actual problems are the real slow response between both sides on selects, inserts or updates. queries that would usually take 2-5 seconds last 1-3 minutes

I would like to know if any of you had to deal with this kind of situations in the past and how you resolve it? if not what are your recommendations?

thanks for the help you could provide.

Comment: Log the queries and the times. Figure out where the time is spent. If it is spent running the queries in the database, get `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this would help anyone in the same situation, even though it's been a few years since this post was made.

Although I was using an ODBC connection, that is not actually the better way to query the database, the application was connected through a very slow vpn to worsen the situation.

The final solution I came across was to locate the app in the same DB server(initially) or internal network(afterward), and serve the app as a remote service, the came to create better responses and performance.